# entity groups and namespaces

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

do namespaces separate entity groups?

lets say i have an app with multiple namespaces and each namespace has 1 entity group and the entity group key is not a real entity but a key construction like.

```
master_group = ndb.Key('Foo', 'bar')
```

if all namespaces have the same entity group key does it count as **1 single entity group** OR is it separated by the namespace which is included in the Key object and there are **as many master_groups as namespaces** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/multitenancy#Using_Namespaces_with_the_Datastore) state that the current namespace is applied to a Key when it is created. [Keys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key_from_path) take a namespace argument. Thus, root entities in different namespaces are in different entity groups.

Comment: that is what i was thinking too but i wanted some confirmation.

Comment: This is correct, though I don't quite follow the reasoning. Keys also take an id argument, but keys with different IDs and the same parent are in the same entity group.

Comment: I was trying to describe the minimum combination of things that determine an entity group, which is why I didn't discuss parents. Also, I was guessing a bit.